# os.makedirs python AttributeError

Tags: python, directory, attributeerror

i'm having a os library error, and it seems that there aren't much info about it on the net. When i try to create a folder in ubuntu 14.04 using my python script:

```
from os  import *

ncpath = "lol"

if not path.exists(ncpath):
    makedirs(path,0755)
```

this error is returned:

```
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 85, in split
    i = p.rfind('/') + 1
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

can someone help me figure out what's going on ?

Comment: dumb me, i guess it's time to get to sleep. thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
makedirs(path,0755)
```

You are passing the `path` module itself instead `ncpath` which is your string.